# Will aptitude be added back in 12.04 or future versions?

Tags: aptitude

Since there is more space in the ISO (750MB for now) for the 12.04 version and the limit of 700MB is removed, has there been any thoughts about adding aptitude to the command line tools.

I ask this since, even though apt-get is recommended, I still find myself working better with aptitude since it has friendlier, all in one command features.

Has it been considered for 12.04 or future versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have no intention of going above 700MB in 12.04. It's an option that Mark has allowed, but we don't think we'll need it, this cycle.

While I also prefer `aptitude`, I don't see it being added. It's not necessary for most users (who'll use `update-manager`) and the users who want it can install it.

Also, `aptitude` is [still unusable on multi-arch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768) :/

Comment: Thank you tumbleweed. Did not actually know about the issue with multi-archs.

Comment: First sentence became invalid after releasing quantal :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any listing of aptitude in the ubuntu cd packages for 12.04 .[[1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/debian-installer/)]